# How to attach multiple files in `message-mode`?

Tags: gnus, message, message-mode, attachment

To attach one file when in message-mode (e.g. when posting from Gnus), one does `C-c C-a`. What's the recommended way for attaching multiple files ?

Repeating `C-c C-a` can become tiresome after a while, because it asks three questions everytime.

Comment: There are two common approaches:  (1) obtain a list of files and loop down the list -- e.g., `mapcar` -- and attach once per element; or, (2) create a loop that automatically prompts yes/no to attach another, and no breaks the loop.  I prefer the file list approach, and I use a real tree-view file manager for Emacs (to simultaneously select marked files in multiple directories to be attached); however, that requires advanced `elisp` modifications.  Most people stick to `dired-mode` and `dired-get-marked-files` and there is a way to operate upon multiple open `dired-mode` buffers.

Comment: @lawlist Thanks. I'd like a file list approach indeed. I obviously don't want to write a lisp loop every time so my aim is to have a command. I'm not sure yet what the interface should look like. I'll think a bit more about and write code it if no ready-made solutions exists.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Open the directory in `dired` with <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> and type `M-x turn-on-gnus-dired-mode`. Then mark the required files with <kbd>m</kbd> (or whatever) and type <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>C-a</kbd>. The files can now be attached to an already opened message buffer or assigned to a new one.

Comment: I wish there was a similar setup as this one for mu4e

Answer (score -1):

Attach a file in Emacs is basically just insert a chunk of string containing file paths, you can use yasnippet to create chunks for you.

Here are the steps:

- in shell, use find/ls to create the files list to attach
- use cli clip tool (putclip on cygwin, pbpaste on Mac, xsel/xclip on linux) to transfer the files list to the yasnippet

Comment: An example chunk would be helpful