# attach multiple files from the same directory to an email message?

Tags: email, mu4e, message-mode

**Q:** how can I attach multiple files to an outbound email with a minimum amount of fuss?

I'm using `mu4e` (which reuses `message-mode`, if that helps) to work with email.  I often need to send emails with multiple attachments.  `mu4e` uses `mml-attach-file` to handle attachments.

So far so good.  However: it's an unpleasant task to use multiple attachments.  `mml-attach-file` prompts for each file anew, which is time-consuming when the file is buried deep in a subtree.

It is almost always the case that, when I need to attach multiple files, they are all in the same directory.  In this situation, **how can I convince `mml-attach-file` to detect an attachment in the existing message buffer and, if it finds one, use that attachment's directory as the default for the next file I attempt to attach?**

NB: If one digs into the source code, `mml-attach-file` relies on `mml-minibuffer-read-file`, which in turn uses either `mml-default-directory` or `default-directory`.

PS: I'm aware of [How to attach multiple files in `message-mode`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14514/how-to-attach-multiple-files-in-message-mode), but there's no answer there.

Comment: **(1)** Do you like the idea of popping open a `dired-mode` buffer from the the email message in `recursive-edit`, then marking the files in `dired-mode` and exiting `recursive-edit` while throwing the result of `dired-get-marked-files`, which is then used by a `mapcar` to attach each file in one fell swoop?  **(2)** Or, do you like the idea of starting in `dired-mode`, marking your files, and then pressing an email generate button that creates the message and attaches all marked files using `dired-get-marked-files` and a `mapcar` to run down the list and attach all files in one fell swoop?

Comment: @lawlist: I've got the dired version going from the [mu4e manual](http://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Attaching-files-with-dired.html), but I'm looking for a way to do this without going through dired.

Comment: I'm a little surprised to see "there's no answer" as an argument for asking a duplicate question. However since your question attracted a valid answer, I guess I'm happy.

Answer (score 13):

I can only suggest a solution for `gnus` and `dired` but it is at least easier as **lawlist** suggested. Open the directory in `dired` with <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> and type `M-x turn-on-gnus-dired-mode`. Then mark the required files and type <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>C-a</kbd>. That's it and the files can be attached to an already opened or a new message buffer (I'm not sure if this works for other MUAs as well)!

Comment: IIUC the OP doesn't want to use `dired`, but if you'd answer my own question (at http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14514/how-to-attach-multiple-files-in-message-mode) I'd be very happy to accept it there.

Comment: @YoungFrog: He should get used to dired as soon as possible ;-)  and thanks for the hint, answered your question.

Comment: @Dieter.Wilhelm: I *am* using `dired`, but also want to have the specific functionality I mentioned in the question.  I'll leave the question open for a bit longer to see if anyone has any ideas on it.

Answer (score 3):

open up a GUI file browser and drag the files to your emacs draft window/buffer

Answer (score 3):

I like to use helm-find-files for this. You navigate to where the files are, mark the ones you want with C-spc, and attach them with C-c C-a (or press tab and find the attach files to email action).

The ivy equivalent of this is counsel-find-file. First, add this action to it:

```
(ivy-add-actions
 'counsel-find-file
 '(("a" (lambda (x)
      (unless (memq major-mode '(mu4e-compose-mode message-mode))
        (compose-mail)) 
      (mml-attach-file x)) "Attach to email")))
```

In this case, you navigate to the files, and type C-M-o then a, and continue to the next file. I don't like this as much as marking them all at once in helm, but I don't often attach many files.

Answer (score 1):

Old post but I got here having the same basic desire and rolled my own
snippet to solve it. For others coming here this might be something
suitable.

```
(defun compose-attach-marked-files ()
  "Compose mail and attach all the marked files from a dired buffer."
  (interactive)
  (let ((files (dired-get-marked-files)))
    (compose-mail nil nil nil t)
    (dolist (file files)
          (if (file-regular-p file)
              (mml-attach-file file
                               (mm-default-file-encoding file)
                               nil "attachment")
            (message "skipping non-regular file %s" file)))))
```

This code means to attach all marked dired "normal" files to a new
message buffer if none exist or add attachments to an existing message
buffer. Works perfect here.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but I want to propose an improvement on @Tompa answer. Here is how to attach multiple files to an existing email:

1. I open a dired buffer and select the files I want to attach
2. I run the following function:

```
   (defun attach-marked-files (buffer)
      "Attach all marked files to BUFFER"
      (interactive "BAttach to buffer: ")
      (let ((files (dired-get-marked-files)))
        (with-current-buffer (get-buffer buffer)
          (dolist (file files)
            (if (file-regular-p file)
              (mml-attach-file file
                (mm-default-file-encoding file)
                nil "attachment")
              (message "skipping non-regular file %s" file)))))
      (switch-to-buffer buffer))
```

3. The function will interactively ask me to which buffer I want to attach the files, and it's done.